# Is there a way to issue a callback without exposing it as a url in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, callback, dom-events

I'm building an application which subscribes to a Javascript event,  and sends out a mail when the event is fired.

At present I'm using a callbacks controller, which then sends the mail via a mailer.  The controller is accessed via an ajax call to the relevant url.

My problem is that I do not want to expose this url for obvious reasons. Is there a way of making the callback without exposing it as a public url?

Comment: What is the "javascript event"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

If you want the server to know when something happens on the client, then the client has to be able to communicate that to the server.

The nature of the web means that you cannot ask a client to keep a secret from its user, so anything the client can do can also be done manually by the user.

Comment: Thanks Quentin ... any other suggestions ?,  validation key perhaps ?

Comment: You would have to give the key to the client, and hence to the user. It is very hard to give a suggestion without knowing what the actual use case is. (See [X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341))